# How do I dynamically change the Jquery mobile slider label in code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Or is there a way to add units of measure to the slider value?

```
<label id="sliderLabel" for="slider">example</label>
        <input id="slider" name="slider" type ="range" min ="1000" max="111000" step   ="100" value="55500" data-highlight="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#sliderLabel').text("New Label");`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zbdQh/ Just click the word 'example' to change the text.